# htaccess php version change & wrong encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, collation

I'm strugelling with strange problem. My hosting provider do not offer cpanel with PHP config option (i know, disaster). For the purpouses of my website I had to change PHP version from 5.2 to 5.5. So admin told me i can use htaccess and command: AddHandler php5.5-fastcgi php

And ok - it activates proper PHP version, but what is totally strange -> change totally my mysql database encoding. The output is following - all posts, pages etc. which were previously displayed in my native language (polish) right now do not display polish diacritic symbols. I've tried to change the whole database collation to UTF8_general_CI yet it didnt solve the problem. I use wordpress as cms, but the issue appears also in my own cms, as well as plain php with mysql. Any ideas how to change that? thanks!

Comment: you need to figure out WHERE the character set change occured. I doubt PHP could do anything to change the in-db stuff. but the php<->mysql connection CAN get changed, as well as php<->client.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the clarification. Do you have any idea how to approach that?

Comment: this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: thank you. unfortunatelly it didnt change anything.

Comment: `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` so we can see if you have utf8 stored correctly.

Comment: PHP 5.4 started using mysqlnd library instead of libmysql. It may be that defaults have changed somehow; did you check your settings in php.ini?